# Applescript: Copy all contents of a folder into every folder in a directory

Tags: applescript

I'm in a bit of a bind and an Applescript noob. I've been stumbling through a script that would allow me to copy the contents of (TemplateFolder) into all of the client folders in a directory, with the added crux that all of the existing clients' folder contents be moved into a folder within the client labeled "Old Files" or something of the sort. I'll include images with my script thus far to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you everyone in advance for all your help.

P.S. Since I don't have the rep required, I'll have to post links to my images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZN2e.jpg

The first image is the template folder (the folder I'd like all contents copied into each client folder).

The second image is an example of an existing client folder with all the bad structure (or lack thereof).

The final image is the expected results where the template folder's contents are moved into the client folder and the original content of the client's folder are moved into a separate folder titled "Old Structure Files".

Below is the applescript I've written, with help from others, to copy the contents. However there are missing components and some elements that need to change; currently the applescript simply copies the entire folder rather than just the contents and it makes a simple copy rather than inserting, the script is not recursive for an entire directory, and there's no function to move the existing client files into a "Old Structure Files" folder. Again, any and all help is greatly appreciated :)

```
on run
    set source_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select folder to be duplicated:" as string
    my do_main_script(source_folder)
end run

on open of source_folder_list
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in the source_folder_list
        set this_folder_path to item i of the source_folder_list as string
        if last character of this_folder_path is ":" then
            my do_main_script(this_folder_path)
        end if
    end repeat
end open

on do_main_script(source_folder)
    tell application "Finder" to set source_folder to folder (source_folder)
    tell application "Finder" to set the target_folder to (parent of source_folder)

    if source_folder is not "" and target_folder is not "" then
        set new_folder_name to (name of source_folder as string) & " duplicate"
        set source_folder to source_folder as string
        set target_folder to target_folder as string

        my create_new_folder(target_folder, new_folder_name)
        my duplicate_folder_structure(source_folder, target_folder & new_folder_name & ":")
    end if
end do_main_script
```

Comment: Another way of achieving this might be to go to the customer folder in the Finder and selecting all the files, right-clicking and making a compressed archive of the existing material and thereby saving space too. Then to distribute the new templates, copy them from their source and paste them into the customer directory... just a thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the script bellow, the template folder is at fixed place on desktop, all the content of the customer selected folder is moved to a new folder "old structure", and after that, all content of the template folder is duplicated into the customer folder. If I well understand, this is what you're looking for :

```
set Templatefolder to "HD:Users:my_user:Desktop:Template"
set CustomerFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select customer folder to be re-organised")

tell application "Finder"
set CustomerData to every item of CustomerFolder
set OldF to make new folder in CustomerFolder with properties {name:"Old Strutucture Files"}
move CustomerData to OldF
set Newstructure to every item of folder Templatefolder
duplicate Newstructure to CustomerFolder
end tell
```